# How to package django app and make available through pip?

Tags: django, pip

What is the best way to package a Django app so that you can make it available to other projects through pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/), they are excellent.

Comment: So you package it up as described in the link and then upload it to PyPi. Is there a standard way to automate releases?

Comment: you change version numbers, run setup.py sdist and setup.py upload. That's it :)

Comment: Perfect, I don't think this article existed when I ran through the tutorial a couple years ago.